# Custom DataSource for TTMessageController

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I am trying to use the Three20 framework for their TTMessageController. It's a great replication of the Apple version, and I need to use it to send custom messages through an API.

I have loaded all of the User information I need from the API (it comes in as JSON but I store it as an NSArray full of NSDictionary objects) and I want the (+) button on the side to bring up a list of users as well as being able to type and convert directly to a contact.

Does anybody know how this is possible?

Comment: I should add that I looked at the example code and it was not helpful at all -- it was far too complicated for what I am doing. I just want to set the data to the view and have it work, all of the examples either use the AddressBook (which I am NOT doing) or use the Three20 connection to get the JSON (which I am also NOT doing).

Comment: typical 320 experience, you have to buy into their world view and eschew standard cocoa, it's a pain in the ass (my opinion) and a bad idea (my opinion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TTCatalog` app contains good example of that, and it's indeed a little complicated. However, I think it's worth using it. Writing your own message compose controller will probably take weeks, and won't look as good as Three20's.

you can copy the code from `MessageTestController` and from `SearchTestController` and use it as is.

Then you will have to change the datasource in `MockSearchDataSource`. It contains an array of the persons that shows up in the search. just try to populate that array from your JSON data and move on from there.